# encogmodel selectmethod configuration

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encog

Could someone point me to examples on how to configure the encogmodel with selectmethod? This is an overloaded method with the first one providing just taking inputs as dataset and method. The second one however allows the following:

1. dataset
2. methodtype
3. methodArgs
4. trainingType
5. trainingArgs

I am unable to get this working as the following error appears "Layer can't have zero neurons, Unknown architecture element:". Any help is appreciated. thank you.
Also, some insight on how to dump the weights in this approach? When the model is built via building the network (BasicNetwork), it is possible to dump the weights as network.flat approach. In this encogmodel driven approach, how do we dump the weights, gradients etc? thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are three examples for EncogModel, you can find them [here](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/encog/examples/guide):

If that does not help, let me know more specifically what you are trying to do, or provide some code that is not working, and I update this to a more specific answer.

The weights can be directly accessed by BasicNetwork.dumpWeights, BasicNetwork.dumpWeightsVerbose(), or more directly with BasicNetwork.getWeight

Comment: Thank you so much Jeff. The said examples use the first option of passing in two arguments. I need to pass parameters including learning rate & momentum to start with.

Comment: I need to pass parameters including learning rate & momentum to start with. I understand there are two possible approaches in creating the network 1) creating pattern and generating a network - here, we will be able to specify the layers, number of neurons, bias(boolean). I believe this is to be used for already normalised files 2) using encogmodel. this is when the file is to be normalised using encog. I see the encoded way of specifying above said params (?->B:method..).

Comment: I am proceeding to go with approach (1) on the basis that weights can be initialized, dumped, only that way. Please correct me wherever I am wrong. Also, please help me understand the diff between a) creating a pattern, setting the activation functinos and generating the network and b) creating network and adding layers with activation functions. thank you again.

Comment: Are there some examples on how to use activationrelu with threshold parameters please?

Comment: I looked at this somewhat, I will try to make this more configurable in next release.  At this point the ReLU threshold is not accessible through the EncogModel.

Comment: thank you. A response to comment on Sep 13 18:55 - difference between option a and b will greatly help. Thank you again.